# What can i do with the ssh host key i got from this nmap scan. (Hack the box)

Tags: ssh, ssh-host-key

I am on hack the box and I ran `nmap -A IP_address` and this is the output I received. I am wondering if I can do something with the ssh hostkey.

[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Do you know what a host key is? https://nmap.org/nsedoc/scripts/ssh-hostkey.html

Answer (score 3):

A SSH host key is conceptually similar to a server certificate in HTTPS. It is considered easily obtainable public information, not secret. There is not really anything you could do with this in terms of attacking the system.

Only if the key is very very weak (like RSA 512 bit) or [known to be compromised](https://manpages.debian.org/wheezy/openssh-client/ssh-vulnkey.1.en.html) you could try to find a matching private key to it and then impersonate the server in a MITM attack. But it is a) very unlikely that this is the case and b) if this is the case then the system is likely much more broken, so there are easier attacks than SSH MITM.

Comment: ok thank you i should of listened to my intuition lol. So let me ask, what would you do if you saw ssh open how would you approach?

Comment: @iammydoom: *"... what would you do if you saw ssh open how would you approach? ..."* - this is a) out of scope of your original question and b) to broad to ask on this site. But a simple search for "attack ssh" would show you that brute-forcing credentials is the typical way to proceed.

Comment: i know i could brute force i have been running the attack for 13 hours and nothing is matching and i was using hydra. What wordlist do you recommend i feel like an idot?

Comment: @iammydoom: again - please stay at the topic of your original question. This is not a discussion site but strict Q+A. If you want to ask a new question then do it as a new question, not a comment.

Answer (score 1):

Not much. That's the server's public key used to verify the identity of the server you are connecting to. Just in case you got overwhelmed, this should give you enough lightweight background reading just in case you got confused https://winscp.net/eng/docs/ssh_verifying_the_host_key

In a CTF scenario SSH is rarely the attack vector. You very likely need to find your entrypoint through other available services. In any case it's wise to take your time to figure out how SSH and other protocols work.